# PostgreSQL: Log statements which do sequential scans

Tags: postgresql, debugging, logging

I use this snippet to detect missing indexes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12818168/633961

Example:

```
SELECT
   relname                                               AS TableName,
   to_char(seq_scan, '999,999,999,999')                  AS TotalSeqScan,
   to_char(idx_scan, '999,999,999,999')                  AS TotalIndexScan,
   to_char(n_live_tup, '999,999,999,999')                AS TableRows,
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relname :: regclass)) AS TableSize
 FROM pg_stat_all_tables
 WHERE schemaname = 'public'
       AND 50 * seq_scan > idx_scan -- more then 2%
       AND n_live_tup > 10000
       AND pg_relation_size(relname :: regclass) > 5000000
 ORDER BY relname ASC;
```

Result:

```
tablename | totalseqscan | totalindexscan | tablerows | tablesize
----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+----------
 mytable  |      112,479 |      2,978,344 | 1,293,536 |   1716 MB
```

I am curious - I would like to see which SQL statements actually does a seq scan on table `mytable`.

Is there a way to let PostgreSQL emit a warning if it does a sequential scan on this table?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get that information as Postgres does not store the execution plans (e.g. like Oracle does)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see no need for storing the execution plan. A warning which gets emitted at the moment of the seq scan is enough for me.

Comment: just curious, pg_stat_all_tables appears to be a view. Is the view definition accessible from the catalog?  I don't have a running psql installation to play with, I tried https://www.db-fiddle.com/ but could not find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is to use the [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) module and enable dumping of execution plans if a statement is slower than e.g. a second.

The plan will be written into the Postgres [log file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHERE)

Then you can have a job that monitors the log file and takes actions if a Seq Scan is part of the plan.

---

A Seq Scan is not something that should be avoided at all costs. It often the fastest way to get the result.

I would focus on plans with Seq Scans, but simply try to find (and then fix) slow queries.

For analysing the logfile you want to have a log at [pgbadger](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger) or you can use [POWA](https://powa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to monitor your server in real time